# Is inheritance in functions possible in Python?

Tags: python

I know with Python classes you can inherit from other classes like this:

```
class A(object):
  pass

class B(A):
  pass
```

However, is this possible with functions? For example, in a Fab file I currently have two functions which do some of the same stuff. I would like a base function so I can stop the duplication of settings.

For example:

```
def environment_base():
    #settings for both environment1 and environment2 here

def environment1():
    pass

def environment1():
    pass
```

I know this is what classes are for but Fabric does not give me the option of using classes for settings.

This is my actual use-case. I have a Fabric file which has two environments i..e `fab environment1 command` or `fab environment2 command`

```
def environment1():
     settings = get_settings(local_path)
     env.git_key = settings['GIT_KEY']
     env.hosts = get_hosts_list(local_path)

def environment1():
    settings = get_settings(local_path)
    env.hosts = get_hosts_list(local_path)
```

As you can see both functions have some of the same settings and does not meet the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle.

Comment: You will have to explicitly call `environment_base`. As far as I know, what you describe doesn't exist in any OO-based language (or even in the OO theory).

Comment: Without a more concrete example, it's hard to offer advice. Note that, although you can't "subclass" functions, but you can make classes `__call__`able.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you use the magic of [decorators](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) for:

```
def p_decorate(func):
   def func_wrapper(name):
       return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))
   return func_wrapper

@p_decorate
def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

print get_text("John")

# Outputs <p>lorem ipsum, John dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: Will that also be possible to initialise stuff, or only on the return value?

Comment: There are a lot of examples out there - try google python decorators example

Comment: @SteveBarnes now I know what they are called I will :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I completely misunderstood your question, but why not just invoking the "base" function from the others?

```
def environment_base():
    # do basic things
    # ...

def environment1():
    environment_base()
    # do env1-specific stuff

def environment2():
    environment_base()
    # do env2-specific stuff
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I said.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: ...well, great minds think alike :-) Note that we submitted our answers at the same time (9:52), I haven't seen yours and you haven't seen mine. One has to type quickly at SO. And let's not start a priority lawsuit :-) BTW, our solution is much clearer than Steve Barnes' magic IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible in Python (or any other OO-based language that I know of).

You will have to explicitly call the `environment_base`:

```
def environment_base():
    #settings for both environment1 and environment2 here

def environment1():
    environment_base()
    pass

def environment1():
    environment_base()
    pass
```

Comment: Would explicitly calling the function allow me to overwrite settings?

Comment: @Sputnik I really couldn't tell without knowing how you write your settings.